# Discrepancy in the Derivation of Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

I am reading Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution for describing the velocities of ideal gas molecules. I went through the PSE question [Derivation of the Maxwell-Boltzmann speed distribution](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144763/338758) and the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) and several other resources for some clarification. The following is my understanding of the concept, derivation, and the discrepancy I am not able to resolve.

For discrete energy levels, the fraction of molecules $q(\epsilon)$, from statistical mechanics, of a particle having energy $\epsilon$ is proportional to $\exp{\dfrac{-\epsilon}{kT}}$. For continuous energy levels, the expression is similar, except that we have to multiply by a factor of $4\pi v^2$, which I will do in the end. The energy of an ideal gas particle is given by $\dfrac{1}{2}mv^2$ and therefore $q(v) = C\exp{\dfrac{-mv^2}{2kT}}$. I am trying to find $C$.

---

Since the particles may have *speeds* in one, $x$, $y$, or $z$, direction ranging from $0$ to $\infty$,

$$
\int_0^\infty C_x\exp{\dfrac{-m(v_x^2)}{2kT}}dv_x = 1\\
\implies C_x=\dfrac{1}{\int_0^\infty \exp{\dfrac{-m(v_x^2)}{2kT}}dv_x}
$$

**Discrepancy:** Several books write that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp{\dfrac{-mv_x^2}{2kT}}dv_x = 1$. I don't think that it is correct, so I am going to carry on with my derivation and give the result using this method in the end.

#### My Derivation

Since $\exp{\dfrac{-mv_x^2}{2kT}}$ is an even function of $v$, we can evaluate the integral as $\int_0^\infty \exp{\dfrac{-mv_x^2}{2kT}}dv = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp{\dfrac{-mv_x^2}{2kT}}dv$. Therefore

$$
C_x=\dfrac{2}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp{\dfrac{-m(v_x^2)}{2kT}}dv_x}
$$

Using trick I learned from MSE question [Integral of $e^{−x2}$ and the error function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1530283/1052701), which I verified using WolframAlpha, I obtained the following result.

$$
C_x = \dfrac{2\sqrt{\dfrac{m}{2kT}}}{\sqrt{\pi}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{2m}{\pi kT}}\\
q(v_x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{2m}{\pi kT}}\exp{\dfrac{-mv_x^2}{2kT}}
$$

I understand $q(v_x)=q(v_y)=q(v_z)$ and $C_x=C_y=C_z$ and $q(v) = q(v_x)q(v_y)q(v_z)$:

$$
q(v) = \left(\dfrac{2m}{\pi kT}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\exp{\dfrac{-mv^2}{2kT}}
$$

Speed is continuous, and we need to multiply by $4\pi v^2$ ([Justification](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144763/338758)) to obtain the final result.

$$
q(v) = 4\pi\left(\dfrac{2m}{\pi kT}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}v^2\exp{\dfrac{-mv^2}{2kT}}
$$

Most textbooks and [ChemLibreTexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/03%3A_Rate_Laws/3.01%3A_Gas_Phase_Kinetics/3.1.02%3A_Maxwell-Boltzmann_Distributions) follow the **discrepancy** and derive the following result.

$$
q'(v) = 4\pi\left(\dfrac{m}{2\pi kT}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}v^2\exp{\dfrac{-mv^2}{2kT}}
$$

---

#### Problems

This is problematic because my result would give different values of well-established $v_{\text{mean}}$, $v_{\text{average}}$, and $v_{\text{rms}}$, being greater by a factor of 8. Could someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just wrong in asserting that those are speeds. Those are velocities, which is why everybody else integrates from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Your mistake of a factor of 8 is just coming from you making this mistake, since $0$ to $+\infty$ is a factor of 2 wrong, we have 3D space, and so $2^3=8$ factor mistake. You have to start with velocities integral, before converting to polar coördinates so as to work with speeds instead of velocities.

Comment: Is this some kind of vectorial integration that I am unaware of?

Comment: No, it is not. You simply misinterpreted those correct integrals.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I am sorry I don't understand it.

Comment: When it is written down as $v_x$, that is very clearly the $x$-component of velocity $\vec v$, and so you have to have both the positive and negative parts integrated. Only when you do the triple integral over all 3 components of the velocity will you get $4\pi v^2$ spherical shell, where $v=|\vec v|$ is the non-negative speed. If you only took the positive half of each direction, then you will not get $4\pi v^2$, and instead get $\frac18$ of that.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you.